# Match multiple Arrays with chunk of Text and return the values if found

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

**In short:** I got 3 Arrays each containing a list of values I want to match against a chunk of text, and if the text contains any of the values from any of the 3 Arrays it should return the values, how would I accomplish that?

**This is my 3 Arrays:**

```
var brand = ['giant', 'trek', 'specialized', 'cannondale', 'cervelo', 'pinarello']

var size = ['48', '50', '52', '54', '56', '58']

var year = ['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2012', '2013']
```

**This is the text, and the positioning of brand, year, size can vary each time in the text**

```
var text = 'specialized Road Expert 2017\nkr.1,150 - Svendborg\n\nspecialized Road Expert str. 44 model 2017\nDenne fantastiske sko passer desværre ikke på mine fødder har været brugt 2 gange. \nKlamper følger ikke med. \nKøbt i Webike Odense 1/3 2017\nNy pris 1.599,-'
```

**I am willing to use pure JS, jquery, underscore, lodash or whatever gets the job done :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var brand = ['giant', 'trek', 'specialized', 'cannondale', 'cervelo', 'pinarello']

var size = ['48', '50', '52', '54', '56', '58']

var year = ['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2012', '2013']

var text = 'specialized Road Expert 2017\nkr.1,150 - Svendborg\n\nspecialized Road Expert str. 44 model 2017\nDenne fantastiske sko passer desværre ikke på mine fødder har været brugt 2 gange. \nKlamper følger ikke med. \nKøbt i Webike Odense 1/3 2017\nNy pris 1.599,-'


var keywords = brand.concat(size, year);

var out = keywords.filter(function(item){
  return text.includes(item)
})

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the values per array, this code will do the job:

```
var result = [brand, size, year].map(function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(word) {
        return text.indexOf(word) > -1;
    });
});
```

Any founds brands are then in result[0], size in result[1] etc.
If you want to merge them together in a single array, use this:

```
var result = [brand, size, year].map(function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(word) {
        return text.indexOf(word) > -1;
    });
}).reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return prev.concat(current);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about case sensitivity or repeated values in your arrays (and you are using es6), then this would work:

```
const res = [...brand,...size,...year].filter(item => text.includes(item));
console.log(res);
```